# bash: &&で実行されるコマンドリストのkill

Tags: linux, bash

以下のようなシェルスクリプトtest.shがあります。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 10);
do
  echo "i=$i"
  sleep 1
done
```

それを以下のように実行した場合、 `kill $P1` でプロセス./test.shは直ちに終了します。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
./test.sh &
P1=$!
sleep 3
kill $P1
echo "end"
```

```
i=1
i=2
i=3
end
```

ただし./test.shのあとに&&で後続コマンドを設定した場合、./test.shは `kill $P1` で終了しません。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
./test.sh && echo "yes" &
P1=$!
sleep 3
kill $P1
echo "end"
```

```
i=1
i=2
i=3
end
i=4
i=5
i=6
i=7
i=8
i=9
i=10
```

なぜこうなるのでしょうか。
また、最初の実行と同じように、直ちにtest.shを終了するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> また、最初の実行と同じように、直ちにtest.shを終了するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

伽語蓮弥の回答にあるとおり、P1には`./test.sh && echo "yes"`のPIDが格納されます。
`./test.sh`はP1の子のプロセスなので、

```
kill $P1
```

の代わりに

```
pkill -P ${P1}　＃親プロセスを指定してkill
```

とすることにより`./test.sh`が終了します。

Answer (score 1):

`$!`は**最後に実行された**バックグラウンド (非同期) コマンドの プロセス ID に展開されます。
最後に実行されたのは`./test.sh && echo "yes"`であって`./test.sh`ではないので`$P1`に入るプロセスIDも別の値です。
なので、`P1=$(pgrep test.sh)`と変更すれば期待通りに動作すると思います。